# Baby Rudin theorem 6.16, explanation that a Riemann Stieltjes integral could be expressed as a infinite series.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, riemann-integration

The theorem says:

Suppose $c_n \geq 0$ for $1,2,3 ...$. $\sum c_n$ converges, $\{s_n\}$ is a sequence of a distinct points in $(a,b)$, and $\alpha (x) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} c_n I(x-s_n)$. Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$. Then
 $$\int ^b _a f d\alpha = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} c_n f(s_n).$$

So I was wondering does $\{s_n\}$ have to be monotone? If not, the coefficient of each $f(s_n)$ in infinite series would not be a $c_n$. Instead, it would be the sum of several $c_n$'s which is the difference between $\alpha(s_i)$ and $\alpha(s_{i-1})$. Am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: No it doesn't have to be monotone. Indeed in general for an infinite set you cannot in general "order" the points. Think of $\mathbb Q \cap (a,b)$ for example.

Comment: If the series is finite, the equality results simply from the formula $\int f \, d(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2) = \int f \, d\alpha_1 + \int f \, d\alpha_2$. The proof of the theorem shows that if $N$ is large enough, then $\sum_{n \geq N+1} c_n$ is small enough that it almost doesn't affect the integral or the sum. The order of the $s_n$'s obviously doesn't matter in the finite case, so there's no reason to think it should in the infinite case.